# Raspberry Pi: How to specify the default runlevel?

Tags: linux, debian, raspberry-pi

I'm setting up a Raspbian Wheezy Pi for my dad with usbip so he can try to control his telescope (USB) over a wireless adapter.

I had the Pi booting into console mode, but after installing the usbip module, it's suddenly booting into graphical mode.  I've run raspi-config and specified text mode, but it's still booting into the graphical interface.

Where can I find the startup scripts which might be specifying runlevel 5 instead of runlevel 3?

While watching startup, I can see:

"INIT: Entering runlevel 5"

Answer (score 2):

Edit `/etc/inittab`. At the top of this file you'll find this:

```
# /etc/inittab: init(8) configuration.
# $Id: inittab,v 1.91 2002/01/25 13:35:21 miquels Exp $

# The default runlevel.
id:2:initdefault:
   ^ Change the default run level here to 3.
```

Comment: It currently shows 2, like you have.  So why is it booting to level 5?

Comment: Nope.  Even changing the inittab to 3, it's still going into level 5.  This all happened after installing usbip... maybe it added a script which calls runlevel 5?  If so, where would I look for it? (bootup scripts)

Comment: I'm going to cry off. You'll need to search through the init scripts. The question is really off-topic for [so], and in this level of detail you're more likely to get help on [raspberrypi.se] or [unix.se]

Comment: Since the change to systemd, inittab is absent. Unclear what